# Change content of UICollectionViewCell during interactive transition

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionview

I'm playing around with `UICollectionView` interactive transitions.
The very basic implementation is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8F5zCK0Hs4lQy15TGZNdjBVLTQ/view?usp=sharing).

Now I'm a bit stuck with Cells transitioning.

The idea is to change content of cells simultaneously with interactive layout transition.

Here is how it looks now.

The first layout

[image]

And the second layout

[image]

When transitioning is finished, I want to change content of cells on second layout.
1) Text label "Some label" should disappear from every cells
2) Text label "Another label" should appear on the right corner of each cell.

**Key issue** is I want this changes fade in/out according to UICollectionViewTransitionLayout.transitionProgress value during transitioning.

Something very similar implemented in Facebook Paper App.
Take look how content of cells is changing below (click on it).

[image]

Is anybody know an elegant way to replicate this effect?

Comment: take a look at pop library from FB, https://code.facebook.com/posts/234067533455773/introducing-pop-the-animation-engine-behind-paper/

Comment: @Vig doesn't helps :-(

Comment: I was going to wait for you to try, but if you want something right away, use the library I have updated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This [library](https://github.com/mukyasa/MMPaper) will help you achieve what you are trying. If you are interested in custom animations I would suggest you use [FB pop library](https://code.facebook.com/posts/234067533455773/introducing-pop-the-animation-engine-behind-paper/)

Comment: The library doesn't do key action that I'm trying to implement. It doesn't changes content of cells. It's permanently     UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"]];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;

Answer (score 0):

Well. 
The solution is to subclass UICollectionViewCell. 
Subclass should contain two `UIView`. One for big layout & one for small.
Initially UICollectionViewCell shows only small one.
Once we starting to update  `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout.transitionProgress` for example from small to big we should do following steps:

1. Make an `UIImage` from big `UIView`
2. Put this image above small `UIView`
3. Set alpha of the image to 0
4. Continuously change alpha of `UIImage` to `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout.transitionProgress` value
5. Once transition is done just switch this to `UIView`

When you transitioning back you should switch big with small.

Done :-)

Comment: Hi Alexey. I'm trying to do the same thing as you. Can you share the code about subclassing the UICollectionView with the 2 UIViews ? Thanks.